# Null Data is passed from Angular 5 to Asp.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular5

When I am passing data from Angular 5 to Asp.Net MVC Controller. it is receiving null data. when content type is changed to **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** the control is passed to controller but with null data. but for json/application it will not pass control to API if it is with [Httppost] attribute.

```
adduser(userdata: User) {
var body = JSON.stringify(userdata);
alert(JSON.stringify(userdata));
return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:21936/UserRegistration/Registration",body,httpOptions);
}
```

Data is not passed from this http call, where User is my MODEL which o created in Angular 5.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserModel usermodel)
{
    using (var dbcontext = new ModelDB())
    {
        UserModel usermodelobj = new UserModel()
        {
            id = usermodel.id,
            name = usermodel.name,
            age = usermodel.age,
            department = usermodel.department,
            mobile = usermodel.mobile,
            email = usermodel.email,
            password = usermodel.password

        };
        dbcontext.userModel.Add(usermodelobj);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

This my MVC Controller

The Model class for Angular 5 and Asp.Net MVC are Same.

Comment: Have you tried `[FromBody]` without `stringify` and with `application/json` as content type?

Comment: Yeah, I tried still passing Null values.In console it is showing error         
     1. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500. 2. {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[FromBody]` attribute to your `UserModel` input

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration([FromBody] UserModel usermodel)
{
    ////
}
```

Comment: Not Working, still Null data.